# Is there a "cancellation" law for vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I apologize if this sounds quite obvious. I'm solving a problem in Axler's linear algebra book which requires me to prove that given $w,v \in V$, there exists a unique $x \in V$ such that $v + 3x = w$. I'm fine with proving existence by letting $x = \frac{1}{3} (w - v)$. To prove uniqueness, I supposed that $v + 3x = w$ and $v + 3x' = w$. Therefore, $v + 3x = v + 3x'$, so $3x = 3x'$. Am I able to "cancel" the $3$? I think there's a property of equality which lets me assert that because $3x = 3x'$, we have $\frac{1}{3} (3x) = \frac{1}{3} (3x')$, but this seems to me to be multiplying a vector by a scalar, which is not allowed. The only alternative way I know to prove this is to write $3x - 3x' = 3(x - x') = 0$ and argue that because $3 \neq 0$, $x - x' = 0$.

So my question is: is there a way to argue that I can "cancel" the scalar $3$?

Comment: Of course you can multiply a vector $v$ in a vector space $V$ by a scalar $\lambda\in K$, from the underlying field. Then $\lambda v\in V$ as well. You did it already for $\lambda=3$. So why not for $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: One of the axioms for a vector space is that $c(dv) = (cd)v$ for all scalars $c,d$ and vectors $v$.

Comment: This seems to be a sincere question with effort, so I don’t see why it was down voted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"but this seems to me to be multiplying a vector by a scalar, which is not allowed."

In fact vector spaces are defined over fields (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$) in order for you to be able to multiply a vector with a scalar, e.g. $3\cdot\begin{pmatrix}1\\4\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3\cdot1\\3\cdot4\end{pmatrix}
$. So, yes, you can cancel 3 by multiplying both sides with $\frac{1}{3}$, which is allowed. :)